# why is $|[a b c]|$ not 24?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors

the question is if $|\vec a|$=2, $|\vec b|$=4 and $|\vec c|$=6 and $(\vec b, \vec c) =\frac{\pi}{2}$. Moreover a is perpendicular to b and c

with this, I've been asked to find $|[ \vec a  \vec b \vec c]|$, where [.] is the scalar triple product.

$|[ \vec a  \vec b \vec c]| = a\cdot (\vec b\times \vec c)$

which means that $a\cdot (|\vec b||\vec c| sin(\theta)$
which is $a\cdot (24|\vec a|$) as the product is either parallel or antiparallel to $\vec a$
so I'm getting 2*24=48

Comment: This is hard to read.  Please edit for clarity.  Starting by defining your notation would be a start.

Comment: done, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Why do you think that $\vec b\times \vec c$ must be parallel or anti parallel to $\vec a$?  Why do you think that $\vec a \cdot \vec b \times \vec c=2\cdot 24 \vec a$?  (Note that the latter appears to be a vector, not a scalar).

Comment: Ok...perhaps you should spend some time editing your post.  It is unusually careless.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting.

Comment: Ok, will do that. Sorry

Comment: Voting to close. The careless editing of this post makes it unanswerable, e.g. the latest edit which removed any hypotheses of perpendicularity.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea; you might start by applying $x\cdot y = |x||y|\cos (x,y)$ with $x = a$ and $y = b \times c$.

Is it given that *all* the vectors $a$, $b$, and $c$ are mutually orthogonal, or just $b$ and $c$? If they were all mutually orthogonal, then the answer would be $|a||b||c| = 2\cdot 4\cdot 6 = 48$.

With the information given, I don't think there is a well-defined answer. You would need to know the angle between $a$ and at least one of $b$ or $c$, or else the parallelopiped* spanned by $a$, $b$, $c$ could have any volume from $0$ to a maximum (in magnitude) of $48$.

*This is one interpretation of the scalar triple product; $|[abc]| =$ the volume of the parallelopiped (like a skewed box) spanned by $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: the question said b and c are perpendicular to a, and separately said that b and c are mutually perpendicular, so I think they are all perpendicular.

Comment: also, could you please explain the third paragraph? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Imagine that $b$ and $c$ are at 90 degrees, and their angle relative to $a$ is unknown. Then $a$ can be rotated all around, changing the volume of the parallelepiped spanned between the three of them (which is proportional to the cosine of the angle between $a$ and $b\times c$), so without knowing the angle of $a$ relative to $b$ and $c$, the answer could be anything between $0$ and $\pm 48$.

Comment: I think I mentioned that a is perpendicular to b and c in the post, did I not?